# Php sql command simply clears database table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

When I try and run this query on my database:

```
$mysqli->query("UPDATE 
         catalogsearch_fulltext 
          SET data_index = '".$unique_string."' 
          WHERE MATCH(data_index) AGAINST ('".$savestring."') 
          AND store_id = '1'");
```

It not only doesn't work, but it clears my ENTIRE `catalogsearch_fulltext` table.  What am I doing wrong?  I'm somewhat new to SQL so this is hopefully a quick error someone can spot.

I can provide more code if requested, but I don't think it is applicable.

Thanks!

Edit:

`$unique_string = "325-FBA-BA-0006-x3|Badger|Enabled|Taxable Goods|Badger - SPF 30+ Anti-Bug Sunscreen, 2.9oz. - (Pack of 3)|47300|You asked, and Badger listened! After receiving many requests for a totally natural combination bug repellent and sunscreen, Badger took their wildly popular SPF 30+ Sunscreen formula and combined it with their Anti-Bug Balm formula to create easy-to-apply, safe, and natural protection for the whole family!|43.35|1"`

```
$string = "the same as above but with duplicat entries in the | Pipe | sections."
```

It is also worth noting that this query is in a loop that goes through about 6 records.

Comment: What is the value of $unique_string and $savestring?

Comment: $unique_string and $savestring are very long but I'll add their values to the post

Comment: An update should NOT delete records, unless you've got a weird foreign key setup or an injection vulnerability of some sort.

Comment: What do you mean by 'clear'. Does it empty the rows (which is possible) or does it REMOVE the rows or even the table (which, as @marc says not normal. unless there's some sort of SQL going on in that variable)

Comment: this is a table in magento (A cms system).  So could this be some sort of protection against updating/inserting records?  Although that would be a considerably ineffective method for defense, destroying itself...I wouldn't put it past Magento

Comment: "clear" as in no entries in the table.

Comment: Are you certain that it's the query (have you run the query directly from sql cli or phpmyadmin)? Or perhaps its an after effect of other code in your processing file?

Comment: Just ran it in mysql workbench...Error Code: 1175. You are using safe update mode and you tried to update a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column.  How do I include a KEY column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $unique_string and $savestring were both uninitialised, I expect you would set your index column to null - which would result in them not showing up in any selects that use that index column?

Perhaps you meant $uniquestring and $save_string? or perhaps these variables are [out of scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)?